# parsing multithreading make's output (-j N)

Tags: multithreading, parsing, gcc, makefile

I have a lot of source directories in common directory. When I start make by issuing command:

```
make -j 4
```

I receive a lot of strings from make's threads along with invoked gcc compiler instances.
For parsing errors I have to run make twice, second time with one thread:

```
make -j 1
```

so I can correctly parse make's output.

Is there a way for running multithreaded make one time and correctly decide which error related to which project (source directory)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using recursive make (naughty boy) together with `-j`, then you can wrap Make with a shell script which prefixes each line of output with a unique per-make-invocation string.

```
$ cat M
#!/bin/bash
PREFIX=$$:
exec -a $0 make "$@" 2>&1 | sed "s/^/$PREFIX/"
```

Now, assuming your makefiles correctly use `${MAKE}` to indicate recursion, we can use `./M` instead of `make`.

```
$ ./M -j --no-print-directory target
28720:/home/user/M -fa.mak
28720:/home/user/M -fb.mak
28720:/home/user/M -fc.mak
28720:/home/user/M -fd.mak
28720:/home/user/M -fe.mak
28720:32484:gcc blah...
28720:31936:/home/user/M -fanother.mak
28720:32484:gcc blah...
28720:31936:gcc blah...
28720:31936:gcc blah...
28720:31936:56781:echo blah...
∶
```

In this case, each line is prefixed with a list of process IDs (good for debugging recursive make). For your use case, you may prefer `M` to mangle source file names so that they become absolute pathnames in error messages.

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow!

Comment: Piping to `sed` hides the exit code of the `make`. You probably want to turn on the _pipefail_ option with a `set -o pipefail` in the script.

Answer (score 1):

May be it is possible to switch to pmake?

> PMake is set up to handle the output from multiple jobs in a graceful fashion ([source](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/pmake/parellelism.html))

Comment: I pass your answer to my collegue who uses all of *make zoo, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using some kind of meta-build system (eg CMake) try using [Ninja](http://martine.github.com/ninja/) to actually run the build.

It solves this problem as well as being quite a lot faster.